# MVC ViewModel not being sent back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've seen multiple instances of this question.  Be that as it may, I still cannot figure out what the issue is with this post method not passing back the model to the controller.  I've looked at naming conventions between the model being passed into the controller, as well as whether or not the read only fields were being passed in if I had removed them.  Other than that, it might be the BindAttribute, binding the RoleIds of the multi-select to the model.

Here's my code:

the model:

```
 public class UserDetail
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> RoleIds { get; set; }
    public string DomainName { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName { get; set; }
    public string TenantDisplayId { get; set; }
    public Boolean InitPassword { get; set; }
    public Boolean Active { get; set; }
    public Boolean SystemAdmin { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RoleDetail> Roles { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectedRoles> SelectedRoles { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList RoleOptions { get; set; }


    public UserDetail()
    {
        Id = Id;
        RoleIds = RoleIds;
        FirstName = FirstName;
        LastName = LastName;
        Name = Name;
        Active = Active;
        EmailAddress = EmailAddress;
        SystemAdmin = SystemAdmin;
    }
}
```

cshtml:

```
@model IzendaEmbedded.Models.UserDetail



 @using (Html.BeginForm("EditActiveDirectoryUser","ActiveDirectory", 
 FormMethod.Post, new {userDetail = Model}))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb" style="height: 100px; padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 140px; background-color: #FFFFFF">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item" style="font-family: arial; font-size:40px"><a href=@Url.Action("Index", "Home")>Izenda</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page" style="font-family: arial; font-size:40px"><a href=@Url.Action("Parse", "ActiveDirectory")>Active Directory</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page" style="font-family: arial; font-size:40px">Edit Izenda User</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>

    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, "Account Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, "First Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, "Last Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "Email Address", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Roles, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.RoleIds, Model.RoleOptions, new {@class = "form-control"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

The controller post method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EditActiveDirectoryUser([Bind(Include = 
    "Id, Name, RoleIds")] UserDetail userDetail)
    {

    //save logic 
    }
```

Comment: What is the constructor for (that is not making sense). Why do you have form controls for `UserName` , `FirstName` etc when you exclude them from binding (because of you `[Bind]` attribute. Your `new {userDetail = Model}` makes no sense - that is adding a (invalid) html attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke You're right, it didn't make sense.  I removed the bind and the constructor and things started working. Thank you.